# Не учитывается достижение дневного лимита голосов

Tags: обсуждение

Мне оставался всего один голос до получения золотого знака "Электорат" (проголосовать 600 раз), система писала, что в следущий раз я могу проголосовать только через 11 часов.

Однако, когда я в очереди проверки на автомате как-то ткнул в upvote -- мой голос засчитался.

> [image: достигнут лимит]

Могу быть уверен, потому что на вопросе вижу теперь закрашенную стрелку вверх (т.е. это мой голос вверх), а также потому что вижу знак "Электорат" в профиле и новогоднюю шапку за золотой знак.

Это дефект, явно.

Update: не дефект. При пересчёте голосов за день нашли один, который я откатил -- его и хватило для повторного достижения лимита.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вопросов и ответов лимит голосов разный. Предположу, что был достигнут лимит голосов за ответы (30), а общий дневной лимит (40) достигнут не был, поэтому удалось проголосовать за вопрос.

---

Похоже, голос освободился после снятия минуса с одного из ответов.

Comment: Вот эта версия к моему случаю однозначно не подходит: я последние пару дней практически только за вопросы голосовал, потому что целенаправленно фармил медальку, а на ответы у меня и так слишком много голосов было отдано ранее. Ну два плюса за ответ, ну пять -- но тридцать? Никак не может быть такого.

Comment: Загляни на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k?tab=votes и проверь.

Comment: И там тоже есть, на табе upvotes. Радует только то, что превышение повторить несколько раз не получится: сработала какая-то ещё блокировка и больше проверять первые сообщения не даёт, хотя там есть что проверять: вижу цифру 1, но тут же горит "Достигнут суточный лимит голосов за/против; возвращайтесь через 3 часа. "

Comment: 1. Я имел в виду не наличие голоса проверь, а пересчитай голоса (отдельно за вопросы и за ответы). 2. И нет ли среди голосов удалённых вопросов/ответов? 3. Не может быть, что ты изменил голос с минуса на плюс? 4. Или до этого отменил какой-то голос?

Comment: А-а-а, точно! Уверен, что я при голосовании обходил вопросы, которые точно удалят -- но [один-то минус я с ответа снял](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4359/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82). Всё, никакой мистики и не баг.

Comment: Кстати, ты же минус во всеми обсуждаемом ответе снял. Не этот ли голос освободился?

Comment: Одновременно догадались :) Похоже, нет бага?